# Export multiple pngs from one Illustrator artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, slices

Another designer left me this AI file while everything is in one layer and in one art board.

I have only exported assets on Photoshop with plugin before and I have no idea how to export individual png from this AI file.

Someone told me to create art board for every single assets then export them but I think that's too time consuming.

Can anyone help?

[image: APP]

Comment: Hi dazedandconfused! I'm afraid you'll need to split all this manually unless someone has a better answer for you! I don't think "slices" work for this and I don't think there's any way for Illustrator to recognize where the graphics start and end. Just select each graphic, copy/paste in a new file. It's not that long to do and you'll be ready to work with proper files named the way you want at least!

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is this: http://www.dehats.com/illustrator-layer-exporter/

Answer (score 1):

Use your direct selection tool to select the points on an area you want the artboard to capture. Click on the artboard tool and pull the menu down to "Fit to selected Art". On the tool bar, name the artboard. Make sure the "Move/Copy" icon is unclicked (not dark) and option drag the artboard to the next part of the art. Use your direct selection tool to select those points and pull the menu down to "Fit to selected Art" again. Repeat for the rest of the art. Then use "File>Export" and make sure "artboards" is checked and it will generate files for the separate artboards. [image]